# Making a button 'disappear' when pressed

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

So I'm trying to make a kind of Wheel of Fortune game or Hangman. I have 33 buttons which represent the alphabet, 1 button = 1 letter. When a user presses one, it has to 'dissapear' (become disable and invisible). I created all the buttons in the SceneBuilder so they are located in the FXML file.

How do I actually do that? I created this method for the first button. But it doesn't work properly, no matter what button I press the first one dissapear. Is there an easier way to do it wIthout writing 33 different methods for each button?

```
public void letterChosen (ActionEvent evt) {
    b1.setDisable(true);
    b1.setVisible(false);
```

Comment: Instead of b1, try the getSource method of the ActionEvent object. This will return the source of the event which will hopefully be the button you're looking for

Comment: Thank you very much, it works now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Button` that was clicked is available as the `source` of the `ActionEvent`.

Additionally `userData` could be attached to the `Button`, in case you cannot get the necessary information to handle the button click from other properties of the `Button`:

```
public void letterChosen(ActionEvent event) {
    Button source = (Button) event.getSource();
    source.setVisible(false);
    System.out.println("pick: "+source.getUserData());
}
```

FXML

```xml
<Button onAction="#letterChosen" userData="a" text="A"/>
<Button onAction="#letterChosen" userData="b" text="B"/>
```

Note that it isn't necessary to disable a `Node` that isn't shown, since a `Node` that is not visible cannot be interacted with. a disabled `Button` will appear "faded" by default, but could also be shown differently, e.g. using CSS.